# Make Pagination In Simple Image Gallery Plugin Joomla

Tags: joomla, pagination, image-gallery

I have website built in joomla 2.5 and I installed simple image gallery plugin in my website. It's working fine but I have 2000 images per page and I need to make pagination for every so user can view 100 images in page and end of the page he can see next prev button for pagination.

Answer (score 1):

If those pages are created by the Joomla Content Extension, then you are probably looking for page breaks (see [Splitting a long Article into multiple linked pages](http://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_a_long_Article_into_multiple_linked_pages)).

For this case, you have to split the gallery into parts, one part for each page. The HTML for the article should look something like this:

```html
<p>Article text...</p>
<hr title="Page 1" alt="Page 1" class="system-pagebreak" />
<p>{gallery}page1/part1{/gallery}</p>
<hr title="Page 2" alt="Page 2" class="system-pagebreak" />
<p>{gallery}page1/part2{/gallery}</p>
<hr title="Page 2" alt="Page 3" class="system-pagebreak" />
<p>{gallery}page1/part3{/gallery}</p>
```

Using this method, if you got 2000 images per article, you are gonna have to make 20 (or 19) page breaks per article.

Comment: hello @Fnatte I think i will have the same problem using pagination in my image gallery. what code shall i use inside the {gallery} if my images are inside a folder? {gallery}images_folder{/gallery} .